# How to combine date and time in Mule4 to get in this format yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Tags: datetime, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have a requirement to combine date which is in this format "2021-09-04T00:00:00-05:00" and time which is a String "37320000" to combine these two to form this format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ" the default value ss.SSS is 00.000. Is this possible to achieve using dataweave 2.0 in Mule ?

Comment: What is the number 37320000 exactly? What kind of time?

Comment: And please share an example of the expected output with those two inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Used your example and here is the dw to achieve the required format. Try here in online [playground](https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/)

**DW**:

((payload.dateTime as LocalDateTime) as Date ) ++
(payload.time as LocalTime {format: "HHmmssSS"}) as String {format: "HH:mm:00"}

**Request Example**:
{
"dateTime": "2021-09-04T00:00:00-05:00",
"time": "12320000"
}

[image]

Comment: The proposed time of "37320000" would parse to 37:32:00.00 which is clearly an invalid time.

Comment: True, i am assuming @rv2509 had a type there. The string "37320000" dos't parse to a valid time in any format.

Comment: We are using X12 connector so the actual HHMMSS converted to milliseconds - 37320000 are milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I found this method decomposing the seconds into hours, minutes and the remainder seconds using simple time math. Then convert to periods that can be added to the original date.

Note that I added 1 millisecond to the input time to confirm milliseconds are represented correctly in the output.

Script:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun addElapsedToDate(date, elapsedMs) =
    do {
        var s=(elapsedMs / 1000) mod 60 
        var m=floor(elapsedMs / (1000*60)) mod 60
        var h=floor(elapsedMs / (1000*60*60)) mod 24
        var ms=elapsedMs mod 1000
        ---
        date + "PT$(h)H" as Period + "PT$(m)M" as Period + "PT$(s)S" as Period

    }
var date="2021-09-04T00:00:00-05:00" 
var duration="37320001"
---
(addElapsedToDate(date as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"}, duration as Number))
    as String {format:"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"}
```

Output:

```json
"2021-09-04T10:22:00.001-0500"
```

If you are using Mule 4.4 you can use the new function [Periods::seconds()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-periods-functions-seconds) to achieve the same result:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Periods
var date="2021-09-04T00:00:00-05:00" 
var duration="37320001"
---
date as DateTime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"} 
    + seconds((duration as Number)/1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 37320000 as Milliseconds I am Providing the Output

```
%dw 2.0
var date= "2021-09-04T00:00:00-05:00" as DateTime {format : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"}
var milliseconds=37320000
var period = ((milliseconds/1000) as String {format : "PT0S"} )as Period
---
date + period
```

output : "2021-09-04T10:22:00-05:00" as DateTime
[image]